# how should I handle a permanent job offer after working as a temporary contract through staff agency?

Tags: job-offer

I have been working for a company for two months through a staffing agency. The company offered me a permanent position which I will work directly to the company, not through a staffing agency. 
I am very interested in it and considering to say "yes".
However, I am currently an employee of a staffing agency which I think I should inform and discuss with the agency about the offer.
I don't know how should I handle to have great terms for all of us. How should I discuss with the agency before accepting the offer? Does anyone know any related policies of a staffing agency and of a company in term of this matter?
What will happen with a staffing agency if I accept the offer? Have anyone been in my situation? I am new to the workforce so I would appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 2):

I'd start by asking the company you're contracting for and which is offering you a permanent job.  They should have an agreement in place with the staffing agency about hiring contractor to permanant.

There normally shouldn't be anything for you to do other than paperwork; your future employer may have to make a payment of some sort to the staffing company as a de facto recruiting fee.

Comment: Exactly so. Temp-to-perm is a very common occurrence for staffing agencies. Your manager and HR department at the company, and your agent at the staffing place all know exactly what to do about this. It's not your responsibility to deal with it. Seriously.  Congratulations, by the way.

Comment: @O.Jones Yes, but it is useful to actually ask the manager or HR at the company and talk to the agent at the staffing agency, because I have heard of things not going well when one of these people who's supposed to know exactly how to handle this failed to think about it. In those cases, most of the time it was just an annoyance for the person who forgot to file the paperwork, but if your HR rep has to do three times the paperwork and pay twice the recruiting fee because they messed up, they may be a little disgruntled in general.  So it's good of the OP to ask.

Comment: @EdGrimm good point. You're right.